# My save data is not being stored in Wildtangent's Game FATE

Tags: fate

I recently downloaded the game again for nostalgia's sake on my pc. I was attempting to save my game and it doesn't appear to work. You start a game, click "Save and Exit", and then the game goes back to the menu and does not contain the "Continue" option, only the New Game one. I have tried a few things:

First, a common suggestion was to start the game as an administrator, and that didn't work.

The next one was to check the file location for the save file and see if the folder was there. I checked and the file was there.
Here is the file location:

Local Disk (C:) > Program Files (x86) > Wild Tangent > Fate > Persistent > SAVE

However, no data is being saved to the folder.

I have also tried changing some compatibility settings in the game properties, but none of them seem to work either.

If I need to provide more information about this issue please do not hesistate to ask. I do also understand that this is an old game, but all help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I have actually managed to solve it. I was being a bit silly. I just needed to reinstall. That seemed to work.